# How to ensure HTML elements have unique ids when repeated in a layout

Tags: html, django

I have a piece of HTML that looks like this

```
{% for job in work_experience %}
<div class="work-exp-item">
    <h4 id="exp-title" class="body-text">{{ job.title }}</h4>
    <h5 id="exp-company" class="body-text">{{ job.company }}</h5>
    <p id="exp-date" class="body-text">{{ job.start_date|date:'Y' }} - 
        {% if not job.end_date%}
            Present
        {% else %}
            {{ job.end_date| date:'Y' }}
        {% endif %}
    </p>
    <p id="exp-location" class="body-text">{{ job.city }}</p>
    <p id="exp-description" class="body-text">{{ job.description }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see this HTML code is inside a DTL for loop and if I have multiple work_experience objects I want to the same HTML to be laid out for different instance of the data. I have ids for the elements, but found that in the final HTML that's produced the ids are not unique. Is there a way in Django to ensure uniqueness like some sort of postfix on each id?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add anything you like to the HTML id attributes; one obvious choice would be to use the id of the job itself.

```
<h4 id="exp-title-{{ job.id }}" class="body-text">{{ job.title }}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use classes for the nested elements inside each div, instead of the same repetitive ids which will cause duplicates and conflicts:

```
{% for job in work_experience %}
<div id="{{ job.id }}" class="work-exp-item">
    <h4 class="exp-title body-text">{{ job.title }}</h4>
    <h5 class="exp-company body-text">{{ job.company }}</h5>
    <p class="exp-date body-text">{{ job.start_date|date:'Y' }} - 
        {% if not job.end_date%}
            Present
        {% else %}
            {{ job.end_date| date:'Y' }}
        {% endif %}
    </p>
    <p class="exp-location body-text">{{ job.city }}</p>
    <p class="exp-description body-text">{{ job.description }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that later I would like to make reference to each element in Javascript

Comment: Ah, got it, then yeah, @Daniel Roseman answer would be your best bet!

Comment: thank you..I really appreciate your input though and has given me something to think about